# See all open files in PL SQL Developer

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I have many files open in PL SQL developer and its uncomfortable to press arrow down to see all of them:

[image: Arrow down for all open files]

How can I see all open files at once like I would in Visual Studio for example (I achieve it by pinning open files):

[image: Visual Studio opened files in two rows]

Comment: What version of PL/SQL Developer are you using? Which menu item has this down arrow? I couldn't find anything like that in version 14.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson that menù pops up only when there isn't enough horizontal space for all the editor tabs (you see tabs when the editor windows are maximized). I see it in pl/sql developer 15, but I think it was there also in pl/sql developer 14... I might be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

under the "view" menu, you can find the option "window list":

[image: view menu contents]

This will show a panel containing the list of all your open windows:

[image: Window list conents]

you can dock this window wherever you want in the main window, and you can save the main window layout in order to keep it in your default layout when pl/sql developer starts.

p.s: you can change the names of the windows in that list (check its context menu)